# Marklogic Rest API for directory-query

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have the following XQuery which I use to fetch documents for a directory.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:directory-query("/Path/To/Docs/", "infinity"))
```

Now I need to translate this into a REST call but I can't seem to crack it following the documentation on this page.

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

**Update:**

using the Jersey REST API, It tried this but got 406 Error

```
String query =  "{\"queries\":[ {\"directory-query\":{\"uri\":[\"/Path/to/Docs/\"]},\"infinite\":true} ]}";

String encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
WebTarget target = searchWebTarget.queryParam("structuredQuery", encodedQuery);

final Response response = target.request().get();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you tried so far?

Comment: Updated with what I tried so far which I found from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189908/marklogic-400-bad-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constraining by directory is a query parameter directly on the search API. NO other notation needed.

See the docs here: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

Comment: When I send this commadd

https://[marklogic-host]:8801/v1/search?collection=&directory=/Path/to/Doc/

I get a response but the uri of the content it is returning do not start with /Path/to/Doc/ but something completely different

Comment: Can you provide an example that will match the above xquery? How will the REST url look like for the above Xquery?

Comment: Solved by url encoding the directory path. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As David said, you don't need to use structured query for this purpose, but in case you have future need:

I believe your original issue was that this is not a well-formed structured query:

```
{\"queries\":[ {\"directory-query\":{\"uri\":[\"/Path/to/Docs/\"]},\"infinite\":true} ]}
```

You're missing the top level "query" property. You can find an example of a fully formed structured query that uses directory-query here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_97452

Also, you're probably already aware, but there is a native Java API that sits atop the REST API. You can learn more about this API here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/index.html

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java